# Python List Comprehension Setting Local Variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I am having trouble with list comprehension in Python

Basically I have code that looks like this

```
output = []
for i, num in enumerate(test):
    loss_ = do something
    test_ = do something else
    output.append(sum(loss_*test_)/float(sum(loss_)))
```

How can I write this using list comprehension such as:

```
[sum(loss_*test_)/float(sum(loss_))) for i, num in enumerate(test)]
```

however I don't know how to assign the values of `loss_` and `test_`

Comment: Have you tried to do that at all? What happened? Where's the code you're actually *"having trouble with"*, and what precisely do you mean by trouble? A [mcve] would help.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with the for loop you have now?

Comment: In Python 2, instead of doing `c = a / float(b)`, do a `from __future__ import division; c = a / b`, see [this PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/). This is the default in Python 3.

Comment: @BasSwinckels thanks

Comment: @MorganThrapp Nothing is wrong with the current code, I would just like to convert into the list comprehension format

Comment: The short answer: you can't save value into variable in list comprehension. So it's not possible.

Comment: @qwertylpc Again, why? It just makes it less readable, especially with this much stuff going on.

Comment: @MorganThrapp I wanted to wrap that into another list comprehension to get a list of lists which I was going to convert into a pandas dataframe

Comment: @qwertylpc put current code inside a function and call this function inside your second list comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a *nested* list comprehension to define those values:

```
output = [sum(loss_*test_)/float(sum(loss_)) 
          for loss_, test_ in ((do something, do something else) 
                               for i, num in enumerate(test))]
```

Of course, whether that's any more readable is another question.

Answer (score 1):

As Yaroslav mentioned in the comments, list comprehensions don't allow you to save a value into a variable directly.

However it allows you to use functions.

I've made a very **basic** example (because the sample you provided is incomplete to test), but it should show how you can still execute code in a list comprehension.

```
def loss():
    print "loss"
    return 1

def test():
    print "test"
    return 5

output = [loss()*test() for i in range(10) ]
print output
```

which is this case will result in a list `[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]`

I hope this somehow shows how you could end up with the behaviour that you were looking for.

Comment: I think the question is not so much "how to execute complex stuff in a list comprehension" but "how to calculate a temp variable once and use it in two places", as OP does with `loss_`.

Comment: @tobias_k explained it better than I could explain it myself

Answer (score 0):

```
ip_list = string.split(" ")                     # split the string to a list using space seperator

for i in range(len(ip_list)):                   # len(ip_list) returns the number of items in the list - 4 
                                                # range(4) resolved to 0, 1, 2, 3 

    if (i % 2 == 0): ip_list[i] += "-"          # if i is even number - concatenate hyphen to the current IP string 
    else: ip_list[i] += ","                     # otherwize concatenate comma

print("".join(ip_list)[:-1])                    # "".join(ip_list) - join the list back to a string
                                                # [:-1] trim the last character of the result (the extra comma)
```